# How to draw Renderbuffer as Texturebuffer in FBO?

Tags: opengl, opengl-es, framebuffer, render-to-texture

I succeeded in render to texture with Texturebuffer, using VAO and shaders.

But FBO has another options for color buffer, it's Renderbuffer. I searched a lot on the internet, but cannot found any example related to **draw Renderbuffer as Texturebuffer with shaders**

If I ain't wrong, Renderbuffer is released in OpenGL 3.30, and it's faster than Texturebuffer.

Can I use Renderbuffer as Texturebuffer? (stupid question huh? I think it should be absolutely, isn't it?)

If yes, please lead me or give any example to draw render buffer as texture buffer.

My target is just for study, but I'd like to know is that a better way to draw textures? Should we use it frequently?

Comment: Can you explain why this is tagged OpenGL ES ***and*** OpenGL? In OpenGL ES _(2.0)_, renderbuffers are even less useful than OpenGL - there is no `glBlitFramebuffer (...)` function to copy their contents to screen.

Comment: Cause I'm studying, FBO & Renderbuffer related with both GL and GLES, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, don't use the term "texture buffer" when you really just mean *texture*. A "buffer texture"/"texture buffer object" is a different conecpt, completely unrelated here.

> If I ain't wrong, Renderbuffer is released in OpenGL 3.30, and it's faster than Texturebuffer.

No. Renderbuffers were there when FBOs were first invented. One being faster than the other is not generally true either, but these are implementation details. But it is also irrelevant.

> Can I use Renderbuffer as Texturebuffer? (stupid question huh? I think it should be absolutely, isn't it?)

Nope. You cant use the contents of a renderbuffer directly as a source for texture mapping. Renderbuffesr are just abstract memory regions the GPU renders to, and they are not in the format required for texturing. You can read back the results to the CPU using `glReadPixels`, our you could copy the data into a texture object, e.g. via `glCopyTexSubImage` - but that would be much slower than directly rendering into textures.

So renderbuffers are good for a different set of use cases:

- offscreen rendering (e.g. where the image results will be written to a file, or encoded to a video)
- as helper buffers during rendering, like the depth buffer or stencil buffer, where you do not care anbout the final contents of these buffers anyway
- as intermediate buffer when the image data can't be directly used by the follwoing steps, e.g. when using multisampling, and copying the result to a non-multisampled framebuffer or texture

Comment: Where do you get this knowledge? via book or just practice a lot? I tried 2 days on the internet but get not much. Almost information of OpenGL I found always in high-level. Asking here when I can't do any thing more.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you have your terminology mixed up.

You attach ***images*** to Framebuffer Objects. Those images can either be a *Renderbuffer Object* (this is an offscreen surface that has very few uses besides attaching and blitting) or they can be part of a *Texture Object*.

Use whichever makes sense. If you need to read the results of your drawing in a shader then obviously you should attach a texture. If you just need a depth buffer, but never need to read it back, a renderbuffer might be fine. Some older hardware does not support multisampled textures, so that is another situation where you might favor renderbuffers over textures.

Performance wise, do not make any assumptions. You might think that since renderbuffers have a lot fewer uses they would somehow be quicker, but that's not always the case. `glBlitFramebuffer (...)` can be slower than drawing a textured quad.